# How to Load Dialog with Different Languages in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, localization, dialog, resources, locale

I am using Visual C++ 2008. In Visual C++, I can define dialog resources in different languages, such as English, German. And the application will load the dialog with the language same as the user current default locale.

However, what if the user default locale is English, but I want to load a German dialog? I cannot find a solution for such a case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. You can create a "settings" section within your application, where the user can specify the locale. Then code logic to prioritise the value in settings (if there is one) over the default locale. Initially the dialog will run in the current default locale, the user will then need to set the locale manually, or you can distribute your application with the settings already in place - e.g. if you are targeting German speaking users with English default locale systems.
2. You can code simple logic to use the German locale if the default locale is English.

Getting and setting locale:

```
std::locale("").name(); /* Get current user locale */
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE"); /* Set to German */
```